# installed nautilus but not placed in menu

Tags: nautilus, xubuntu

I am using Xubuntu 13.04. I have nautilus  because I like it. But I haven't found them in the main menu.

is there **any way** I can **add them to main menu** of Xubuntu desktop.I have already check for the entries in the `/usr/share/applications`

```
jai@frank-Jai:~$ sudo ls /usr/share/applications | grep nautilus
[sudo] password for jai: 
brasero-nautilus.desktop
nautilus-autorun-software.desktop
nautilus-connect-server.desktop
nautilus.desktop
nautilus-folder-handler.desktop
nautilus-home.desktop
```

Answer (score 1):

The `nautilus.desktop` file from your list shows why:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Files
... translations...
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;Core;
```

Adding `XFCE` to `OnlyShowIn` will make nautilus appear as `Files` under `Utility`.

Note that the `xfce4-appfinder` finds it even without this edit.

Also note that if you really needed `sudo` to list the contents of `/usr/share/applications`, the menu should come up empty.